# Is Node a superclass of all content type?

Tags: nodes

I have been trying to understand drupal 7 internals. It seems to me that the concept of node is like a superclass in OO languages. All other content types are the derived classes of Node.

Please let me know if this wrong.
Thanks.
DB

Comment: A node is not a content type, see https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/node

Comment: Node is the entity and the content type (for example "basic page") is a bundle of that entity. It's not OO *technically*.

Answer (score 2):

From drupal.org: [An Introduction to Entities](https://www.drupal.org/node/1261744)

> If you come from an OOD/P background and are trying to better
>   understand what these key D7 concepts are, the following suggested
>   mapping might help (albeit not strictly true from a purist’s
>   perspective) :-
>
> ```
> An entity type is a base class
> A bundle is an extended class
> A field is a class member, property, variable or field instance 
>     (depending on your naming preference)
> An entity is an object or instance of a base or extended class
> ```
>
> All these four OOD/P concepts are special in that they are
>   serialisable (stored - e.g. to a database or file). Serialisation
>   takes place via the Entity API.